# nodejs casperjs ejs express: settings values not seen by casperjs

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs, ejs, casperjs

CasperJS doesn't seem to be able to see values passed from express via app.settings.  Is there something I am leaving out?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point me to a solution!

Here is a hello world node server:

```
hello.js
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.configure(function()
{
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', __dirname);
    app.set('message', 'hello world!');
    app.set('secretmessage', 'foobar');

    app.get("/", function(req, res)
    {
        res.render('index.ejs', { layout:false });
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
});
```

In the same folder:

```
index.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="hidden" id="secret" value="<%= settings.secretmessage %>">
      <p><%= settings.message %></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I start with `node hello.js` it tells me appropriately that the server is listening:

`Express server listening on port 3000`

Here is the html returned, as seen by Firefox - it is as you would expect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="hidden" id="secret" value="foobar">
      <p>hello world!</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to test this with casperjs.  Here is my test code:

```
indextest.js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start( 'http://localhost:3000', function start()
{
    var secretExists = this.evaluate( function() { return __utils__.exists( '#secret' ) });
    var secretValue = this.evaluate( function() { return __utils__.getFieldValue( 'secret' ) });
    casper.test.comment( 'Confirming hidden field secret exists and has value' );
    casper.test.assert( secretExists, 'secret exists' );
    casper.test.assertTruthy( secretValue, 'secret has value' );
});

casper.run(function run() {
    casper.test.done();
});
```

And here are the results:

```
$ casperjs indextest.js
# Confirming hidden field secret exists and has value
PASS secret exists
FAIL secret has value
#    type: assertTruthy
#    subject: ""
```

Instead of seeing the value of `secret` as "foobar" it is seeing it as "".

Comment: A small syntax error was pointed out to me, which I have corrected in the casperjs code above.  The result turns out to be the same, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that while `__utils__.exists()` uses the CSS selector, `__utils__.getFieldValue()` uses the 'name' attribute.

Adding the `name="secret"` attribute in index.ejs thus:

`<input type="hidden" id="secret" name="secret" value="<%= settings.secretmessage %>"`

causes both tests to pass.  Thanks to V.P. for the solution!